# When using useAnimate hook I got the error: No valid element provided

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, framer-motion

The line: `await animate(scope.current...` throws an error: `Error: No valid element provided.`

I am using regular React-three-fiber canvas. I tried to use `<MotionCanvas/>` but it would throw other weird error. When I try basic `animate` operation inside `<motion.group>`component, it works all well, but I want to work on more complex animations so `useAnimate` is a perfect hook for that, but unfortunately I am not able to make it work.

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion-3d"
import { useAnimate } from "framer-motion"

export const PlayerCard = ({ imageUrl, position, cardIndex, cardShape, cardBody }: PlayergCardProps) => {
   const playerCardState = useRecoilValue(playerCardAtom);
   const playerCardActions = usePlayerCardActions();
   const [scope, animate] = useAnimate()

   useEffect(() => {
      if (playerCardState.isPicked === cardIndex) {
         animatePickCard(0.5)
      } else {
         animatePickCard(0)
      }
   }, [playerCardState.isPicked])

   const animatePickCard = async (z: number) => {
      await animate(scope.current, { z: z }, { repeat: Infinity,
         repeatType: "mirror",
         ease: "easeInOut",
         duration: 1
      })
   }

   function handleClick() {
      playerCardActions.pickCard(cardIndex)
   }  

   return (
        <motion.group ref={scope} whileHover={{scale: 0.5}} position={[position.x,position.y,position.z]} scale={[0.45, 0.5, 0.5]} onClick={handleClick}>
          {/* Card body */}
          <motion.mesh position={[0, 0, 0.1]} castShadow>
            <motion.bufferGeometry attach="geometry" {...cardBody} />
            <motion.meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color={"#51CF66"} />
            <motion.meshPhongMaterial attach="material" color={"#51CF66"} />
          </motion.mesh>
        </motion.group>
      )
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of a solution, but it does provide more complex capabilities to motion components.

Instead of `useAnimate()` hook I imported `useAnimation()`, assigned it to animate prop in <motion.group> and took out the ref. The code looks something like this now:

```
import { useAnimation } from "framer-motion"

...

const animationControls = useAnimation();

useEffect(() => {
    const enemyPosition = playerCardState.attackingCard
    if (playerCardState.isPicked === cardIndex && enemyPosition) {
      animateAttack(enemyPosition?.x, enemyPosition?.y, enemyPosition?.z, true)
    } else {
      animateAttack(position.x, position.y, position.z, false)
    }
  }, [playerCardState.attackingCard])

  const animateAttack = async (x: number, y: number, z: number, setInitial: boolean) => {
    await animationControls.start({ x: x, y: y, z: z}, { duration: 0.5 });
    if(setInitial) {
      playerCardActions.attackCard(null)
      playerCardActions.pickCard(null)
    }
  }


return (
   <motion.group animate={animationControls} whileHover={{scale: 0.5}} position={[position.x,position.y,position.z]} scale={[0.45, 0.5, 0.5]} onClick={handleClick}>
      ...
   </motion.group
)
```

I am able to do more complex animations using multiple states so it does what I want it to do. However I am still unable to really solve the error I struggled with using `useAnimate()` hook.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for the solution. but why useAnimation is not working may it is made for html elements not for theeJS elements?